# How to get country name for users in laravel 5.1

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.1

Hello i have two tables users and countries, and each user belongs to the country. So i created two models User and Country

In User Model i put

```
public function country_living()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country');
}
```

In country Model i put

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\User');
}
```

Now when i am selecting all users for listing in backed i am using below code

```
$users = User::where('user_type', 'customer')->get();

and in view i am using @foreach($users as $user)
```

to display all the user information, i don't know that country name is coming by query or not and if it is coming how to show it. when i use dd() on $user there is no information about country.

Answer (score 0):

```
UserModel
```

public function Country()
{

> return $this->belongsTo('Country');
>
> > }

```
Countrymodel
```

public function User()
{

> return $this->hasMany('User');
>
> > }

```
View.php
```

@foreach($User as $user)

> {{$user->id}}
>   {{$user->name}}
>   {{$user->country_id}}

Comment: in controller --->
  `$user = User::all();
            return view('userprofile.view')->with('User',$user);`